# Automatically add Content-Type to incoming HTTP requests if missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.Net WebAPI service to allow embedded devices to transfer data in semi-realtime.

These devices will be on a capped wireless broadband plan, which means that low data consumption usage is a requirement for this project.

The devices will send data through HTTP in JSON format.
At the moment, I include "Content-Type: application/json" in the header, which works well.

However, I'm thinking it is a waste of precious bytes (and data usage plan) to send these few bytes over the wire everytime.
I can be 100% sure, at the moment that the data sent will be encoded by JSON, so I would rather have the server assume the Content-Type when it is missing.

However, if I omit it, my Post controllers do no trigger anymore when the client posts to them.
They are declared like that:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] MyEvent myEvent)
```

In short, what I'm trying to do is to automatically add, on the server-side, the Content-Type to the incoming HTTP requests that the client would have omitted to add, or another way of making my controllers work and automatically deserialize the JSON message, even with that Content-Type header entry is missing.

I'm hoping there might be a source code file or configuration on the WebAPI project where I could configure that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement an action filter for incoming requests probably

Comment: _"if I omit it, my Post controllers do no work anymore"_ - with what error? Did you get any meaningful results when you searched the web with that error?

Comment: If you are so worried about saving bytes, why are you using JSON? Wouldn't a binary format (BSON) be more suitable?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Thanks. Any pointers/good examples?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't get any error, they just don't trigger anymore (I assume because the controller thinks it is not JSON.

Comment: @KharlosDominguez IU'm not sure if that will actually work, but yo ucan just google for web api action filters adn try to modify the content type in `OnActionExecuting` method

Comment: @Lloyd true, along these lines, we shouldn't be using HTTP either but a custom protocol. However, there are other requirements which force us to use JSON and HTTP because we want to be standard and have good compatibility and interoperatibility. The messages are short though, so JSON is not really that big of a problem. Actually, I'm asking this because I'm kind of bothered that my header is in some cases larger than the body, which seems a waste of bytes.

Comment: This is the sort of problem that HTTP 2.0 is meant to solve (because of header compression and a way to basically say "this request uses the same header as this previous request") but it's not ready for prime-time yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class ConTypeFilter:DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {        
        if ( request.Content.Headers.ContentType==null)
        {
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType=new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And in your `Application_Start()` add the following.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new ConTypeFilter());
```

Thanks to [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

Comment: Thanks. However, when posting to my controller, I still get error 415 (Unsupported Media Type). I have properly decorated the controller's Post method with the ConTypeFilter attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A rather late reply but I thought I should share it as I got into similar issue and after some research found following solution.

```
    public class AddMissingContentType : Attribute, IResourceFilter 
    {
        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Type"))
                context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        }
    
        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

and then add it as follows in your method

```
[AddMissingContentType]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] MyEvent myEvent)
{
   // Your code goes here
}
```

Thanks to [Alex Riabox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9608718/alex-riabov) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347953/asp-net-core-http-delete-frombody-ignore-if-no-content-type-header).