# Modifying Content-Type of incoming SOAP request

Tags: c#, soap

The client refuses to add `Content-Type` when they call our WS.

I tried the method suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983065/automatically-add-content-type-to-incoming-http-requests-if-missing), it doesn't work though.

```
public class ConTypeFilter:DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {        
        if ( request.Content.Headers.ContentType==null)
        {
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType=new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Is there any other method that can intercept the request and add header to inbound requests?

The reason i want to modify it is because SOAP WS dropped messages of content-type different than `text/xml` or `application/soap+xml` while users said they will send in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and refuses to change.

Answer (score 1):

Other way to intercept messages from client is through before and after method :

```
#region IClientMessageInspector Members
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message   reply, object correlationState)
{
  Console.WriteLine("IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply called.");
  Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", reply.ToString());
}

public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
   Console.WriteLine("IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest called.");
   return null;
}
```

For more details see link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not the client though. They are. They refuses to add `Content-type` which force me to go with the route: intercepting msg and adding `Content-type` myself at the WS.