# asp.net core http delete `FromBody` ignore if no content type header

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

I am using a body in a http `DELETE` request. I know having a body in a delete is non-standard at the moment (but is permissible).

The problem is occurring when using the `HttpClient` which does not allow a body for delete requests. I know I can just use `SendAsync`, but I would rather make my API more flexible.

I want this body to be optional. In the sense that if asp.net core cannot ascertain the content type then ignore it. At the moment, asp.net core is returning a 415, even though no body is being sent (via the `HttpClient` - so content length should be 0).

Can `FromBody` be extended in this way? Or would I need some custom logic in the pipeline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create ResourceFilter which is executed before Model Binding where content type is checked:

```
public class AddMissingContentType : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

And add it to your method:

```
[AddMissingContentType]
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody]RequestData request)
{
}
```

Comment: Is IgnoreMissingContentType really a good name when the filter adds a content type to the header?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund you're right, I was thinking more of intention instead of what it actually does. I've changed the name

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to manually fetch the body in the controller method. You could check for the content type if it exist or just use a default reader, such as json, and convert it to your model  that way. Then you don't need to modify any request headers

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task Delete()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, encoding))
    {
        var bodyContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyContent))
        {
            //mapp the bodyContent to your model
        }
    }
    //perform the logic which should allways be done
}
```

NOTE: Important to leave out the FromBody parameter in the method signature, else the binding will fail when the content type or body is missing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert it to a POST if you will use your ~app as an API behind a proxy, load balancer or other stuff you don't have control on...

Example: some load balancers can consider a DELETE method with a body as malformed. 
But if you are sure about your future environment, why not...

EDIT: The answer is: even if it's possible, maybe it's better to follow rules that are sometimes applied and sometimes not to don't have any further surprises. (--cannot comment I m a new born user).

Comment: This can be a comment but not an answer.